# Necessity of domain layer on android architecture

Tags: android, architecture

I using MVP pattern with Rx and dagger for android development. I'm confused with the necessity of "domain" layer in the following [clean architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/). It looks like there will be lot of code duplication between data and domain.

```
View <-> Presenter <=> Domain <=> Data (local/remote)
```

How will development be affected(ease, maintain and test) id I were to use the following?

```
View <-> Presenter / Domain <=> Data (Local/remote)
```